# How to search for list of files with specific extension present in a branch using gitlab api

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-api

Not able to find the list of all files with "csv" extension in a branch named av.
Tried this

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/101010/repository/files/av.csv?ref=av
```

as the command requires complete name not with *.csv.

Is it possible with gitlab api ?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) api able to listdown the files under a specific branch.

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer <private token> -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{ "query": "{ project(fullpath: \"'<full_path_of_project>'\") {repository {tree (ref: \"'<Branch_name>'\", recursive: true){ blobs{ nodes {name}}}}}}"}' -k https://git_url.com/api/graphql | grep -io '"\([a-z.]*\)csv"' | sed -e 's\"\\g'
```